# Subdomain hosting

Tags: windows-server-2008, subdomain, iis-7.5

I have www.mydomain.com hosted elsewhere. I have the registrar point mysubdomain.mydomain.com point to Windows2008 r2 a completely different server. I go to edit bindings for the site add mysubdomain.mydomain.com  but it never works bringing up the site.

Comment: You probably have some type of configuration error on the new sever. Your setup should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is your registrar the DNS host? You must also make sure it created an A-record for the subdomain to point to your Win2008R2 server. Try to ping your subdomain and see where it resolves. If the ip address resolves to something else than your Win2008 server, then it's a DNS misconfiguration. If the IP address is your Win2008 server, then it's a configuration problem on IIS.

Comment: I am using 1and1 as the registrar I followed their directio for a record a while ago but the  dns check points for mysubdomain.mydomain.com  points to  mydomain.com which has other nameservers but another domain that has 1and1 domain server names allows the mysubdomain.mydomain.com  to point to the server if the  mydomain.com  points to it too.So for 1and1 the A record seems immaterial. It matters where the domain.com points to.